# Frequency Table by range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two arrays in Python with random numbers:

```
vn = np.random.normal(20,5,500);
vu = np.random.uniform(17,25,500);
```

I'm trying to create a Frequency table with pandas to have a count of the occurrences by range, but I really have no idea on how to do it, an example input and output would look like:

input:

```
vn: [2,3,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,7]
vu: [1,1,2,3,6,7,7,7,8,9]
```

output:

```
Range     count_vn     count_vu
(0, 5]        2            4
(5, 10]       8            6
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [228]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=[0,5,10]).value_counts()).add_prefix('count_')
Out[228]:
         count_vn  count_vu
(5, 10]         8         6
(0, 5]          2         4
```

or a nicer solution provided by @ayhan:

```
In [26]: df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, bins=[0,5,10])
Out[26]:
               vn  vu
(5.0, 10.0]     8   6
(-0.001, 5.0]   2   4
```

somehow it produced "strange" bins...

Comment: Hey, in this case the output shows always 5, as if it was counting the occurences of the index in the range, instead of the actual values in vu and vn, Thank you

Comment: @Colanta, i've updated my post - is that what you want?

Comment: Ah! That's it!:). My solution looks way too convoluted in front of this

Comment: @MaxU Indeed, thank you very much, i need only to find how to order the ranges, because after (1.5, 2] it follows (10, 10.5] but i markes as solved, thank you very much

Comment: value_counts also acceps a bin argument so you can do things like `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, bins=[0,5,10, 15, 20])`

Comment: @ayhan, it looks much nicer, thank you! Somehow it produces "strange" bins for me...

Comment: Note: Use pd.cut() when you need to segment and sort data values into bins. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try pd.cut with groupby and then concat the dataframes.

```
vn= [2,3,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,7]
vu= [1,1,2,3,6,7,7,7,8,9]
df = pd.DataFrame({'vn': vn, 'vu': vu})
bins = np.arange(0,df.stack().max()+1,5)
pd.concat([df.groupby(pd.cut(df.vn, bins=bins)).vn.count(),\ 
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.vu, bins=bins)).vu.count()], axis = 1)
```

You get

```
        vn  vu
(0, 5]  2   4
(5, 10] 8   6
```

There might be a way to do it directly without concat but I couldn't come up with any