# Frequency Table by range in pandas returns 1 or 0

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this

```
Total
0
0.5
1
1.5
2
2.5
10
10.5
11
11.5
12
12.5
5
5.5
6
6.5
7
7.5
15
15.5
16
16.5
17
17.5
```

I'm trying to get a frequency table of the above data following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806458/frequency-table-by-range-in-pandas) answer

```
graph = df['Total'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])
```

But I'm getting this result
[image]

Why am I not getting the actual count? And why is the range so weird? Im using Python 3.8.5 and Pandas 1.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your desired output? Eg is this what you are after:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Total'], bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])).count()
```

output

```
            Total
Total   
(0, 10]     12
(10, 20]    11
(20, 30]    0
(30, 40]    0
(40, 50]    0
(50, 60]    0
(60, 70]    0
```

Comment: In this way won't 0s be left out of the count?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum them up

```
df['Total'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]).sum()
```

output

```
(-0.001, 10.0]    21
(10.0, 20.0]      15
(20.0, 30.0]       0
(30.0, 40.0]       0
(40.0, 50.0]       0
(50.0, 60.0]       0
(60.0, 70.0]       0
dtype: int64
```

## update

Or better

```
df['Total'].apply(
    pd.Series.value_counts, 
    bins=np.arange(0, 101, 10)
).sum()
```

output

```
(-0.001, 10.0]    21
(10.0, 20.0]      15
(20.0, 30.0]       0
(30.0, 40.0]       0
(40.0, 50.0]       0
(50.0, 60.0]       0
(60.0, 70.0]       0
(70.0, 80.0]       0
(80.0, 90.0]       0
(90.0, 100.0]      0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: But why are the ranges not in order and why (-0.001, 10.0]?

Comment: with `df['Total'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, bins=np.arange(0, 71, 10))` I get them in order. Pandas `'1.2.3'`. @piterbarg solution solves (-0.001, 10.0]

Comment: -0.001 is need to count 0s in the first bin